# XSD to xsl or html form using php

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xsd

I've such .xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<xsd:complexType name="user-wrap">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="user" type="user" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="user">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="company" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="site" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="country" type="country" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="country">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="RU"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="US"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="KZ"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

It's not full, there's about 100 fields.
So, I need to make an XML file using that xsd schema. User must fill the information to some form. Can I generate that form(maybe HTML page or XSL table) using that xsd? And just fill the XML file by that form authomatically.
100 fields is too much to hand-parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Microsoft InfoPath (part of MS Office).

This sounds exactly like the tool you need. It supports the creation of forms from XSD and translates form data into compliant XML instances.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/infopath-help/design-a-form-based-on-an-xml-schema-RZ001122374.aspx

Apologies this is not a php tool.